# MSSQL: Automatically filling a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a query for automatically filling a table. The table has:

- ID(Primary Key)
- FormID
- ObserverID
- ObservationID
- ObservationAnswerID

which are primary IDs of other tables which have relationship with said table.

I need a query that will take the IDs and will add them in the table.

For example the ObservationTable includes:

- FormID
- ObservationID
- ObserverID

Comment: What is the logic that you want to use?

Comment: Please read [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and update your question !!!

Comment: I`ve done it with C# console app but I need to do it inside SQL.

Comment: do you want it done everytime you add new data to other tables or this is one time load?

Comment: It would be better if it runs every time some data is added to the tables but it is not so important. One time load is suitable also.

Comment: In that case all you need is `INSERT INTO FROM` select statement. Without you specifying structure of all your tables it will be impossible to give you a query.